# Apache Camel Quartz RejectedExecutionException

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

While running a `quartz` camel route at a certain time (`cron-job`) which generates a ~1MB of a file and uploads it to FTP.

It is throwing below error and it is **intermittent** (sometimes I get no error till the end of the process). 
It is getting nearly impossible to reproduce the issue in my local. However, if I try to update the camel route in an ongoing `cron-job` it will throw exactly the same error,

How do I solve this?

**Error:**

```
[ERROR] org.apache.camel.component.quartz2.CamelJob - Error processing exchange. Exchange[ID-sw-prod-esb-01-40406-1534255789208-0-272116]. Caused by: [org.quartz.JobExecutionException - java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException]

[INFO ] 2018-07-06T10:20:11,772 [test-camel-quartz-scheduler-instance-camel-1_Worker-9] [{cId=a6b1a4d6-7df3-40a3-8a70-b57aa}] org.quartz.core.JobRunShell - Job DEFAULT.quartz-endpoint528 threw a JobExecutionException: 
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzEndpoint.onJobExecute(QuartzEndpoint.java:147) ~[camel-quartz-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.CamelJob.execute(CamelJob.java:63) ~[camel-quartz-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:223) [quartz-1.8.6.jar:?]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549) [quartz-1.8.6.jar:?]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:428) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.QueueLoadBalancer.process(QueueLoadBalancer.java:44) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerSupport.process(LoadBalancerSupport.java:97) ~[camel-core-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzEndpoint.onJobExecute(QuartzEndpoint.java:143) ~[camel-quartz-2.19.0.jar:2.19.0]
    ... 3 more
```

**Route Defination XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
   <route>
      <from uri="quartz://Test/DataUpload?cron=0 50 15 ? * * *&amp;trigger.timeZone=Asia/Calcutta" />
      <log message="Starting here" />
      <to uri="bean:SomeProcessor" />
      <log message="after processor" />
      <split>
         <simple>${body}</simple>
         <to uri="bean:TransformProcessor" />
      </split>
      <log message="ending here" />
   </route>
</routes>
```

**Edit:**

While analyzing logs I can see log "Starting here" and when it enters SomeProcessor.java there is no exception either, but log "after processor" is not printing.

**SomeProcessor.java**

```
Map<String, String> searchAttributes = buildSearchFilterAttr(exchange);
        Set<Order> orderSet = new HashSet<Order>();
        logger.info("fetching {}", searchAttributes);
        try {
            dataSet = cleint.someAPI(....);
            logger.info("total number {} ", dataSet.size());//300
            exchange.getIn().setBody(dataSet);
        } catch (IOException | BadRequestException ex) {
            logger.error("error");
            throw new SomeCustomException(errMsg, ex);
        }
```

Comment: Could you post your route definition? It is hard to answer this question without it.

Comment: @Bedla added route definition.

Comment: I dont see any issue in route. Just a guess, are you stopping this route yourself in code or is Context shutdown in progress? This exception is expected in some cases of shutdown if redelivery is still in progress.

Comment: @Bedla No I do not stop/shut down anything, I have updated the question with java code.